# Counting elements in a list with a given number of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, list-comprehension

I want to create two lists. The first has x elements, 'Name n'

When x=4, for example:

```
names = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4']
```

Comment: Start with an array filled with `Not Lucky`.  Execute a function that returns a random number between zero and the length of your array minus one.  Use that number as your index to the element in your array that you will change to `Lucky`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import random
>>> x = random.randint(0, 10)
>>> x
6
>>> lucky = random.randint(0, x)
>>> lucky
3
>>> ['Name %s' % x for x in range(0, x)]
['Name 0', 'Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4', 'Name 5']
>>> ['Lucky' if x == lucky else 'Not Lucky' for x in range(0, x+1)]
['Not Lucky', 'Not Lucky', 'Not Lucky', 'Lucky', 'Not Lucky', 'Not Lucky']
```